# Can I use shocks for a 4 inch lift with a 2.5 inch lift?

Tags: lift-kit

I'm going to lift my Jeep wrangler and I would really like to use fox racing shocks which are for 4 inch lift kits, but I really don't need a 4 inch lift and they cost a whole lot.  Would it work to use the 4 inch shocks with a 2.5 inch lift kit?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with the exact application, but in general it's a bad idea putting longer shocks into lower vehicles.  That's assuming that the left kits don't actually move the mounting points too and retain the same length/travel requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In short no.Any competent 4x4 shop will tell you.Bear in mind big lifts raise centre
of gravity which will impair stability particularly with a laden roof rack.